# Find all functions satisfying $f\left(f(x)f(y)\right)+f(x+y)=f(xy)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

Find all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $$f\left(f(x)f(y)\right)+f(x+y)=f(xy)$$

The only thought i could get is clearly $f(x)=0$ satisfies. Also if $f(x)$ is an even function the functional equation is alsways true, but no clue for finding those functions.

Comment: As a guess, $f(x)\equiv 0$ and $f(x)=x-1$ are  both solutions.

Comment: Yes and obviously $f(x)=1-x$ too satisfies

Comment: See here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362996/