# Finding all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the given property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-equations

> **Problem** :  Determine all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that, for all real numbers $x$ and $y$,
>
> $$f \Big(f(x)f(y)\Big) + f(x + y) = f(xy)$$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362996/ffxfyfxy-fxy

Comment: This is a contest problem.