# IMO 2017: Determine all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ such that, for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, $f(f(x)f(y)) + f(x +y) = f(xy)$.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, contest-math, functional-equations

> **EDİT**: I think I've repair the error in the solution. I want to know if I'm fixing it properly. I'm just a student, not a mathematician. Please focus on the "backbone" of my writing.

I want to prove that, the following substitution is correct:

> $$ x\mapsto f^{-1}(x)$$

**Statement**: For a function to have an inverse, each element $y ∈ Y $ must correspond to no more than one $x ∈ X; $a function $f$ with this property is called one-to-one or an injection.

The function $f(x)$  is an injective and $f$ is an invertible function. In other words, if $f(0)≠0$, for function $f(x)$, the inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$ is exist.

$f(x)=f(0)-\frac {x}{f(0)} \Rightarrow f^{-1}(x)=f(0)(f(0)-x)$ and  $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb {R}$. For this reason, we can applying the substitution $ x\mapsto f^{-1}(x), x\in\mathbb{R}.$

For example:

If $f(f(x))=f(x)-5 , x\in\mathbb{R}$, then  $f(x)=x-5$ must be. Because,  the function $f(x)$  is an injective and $f$ is an invertible function. Applying  $x\mapsto f^{-1}(x)$ we have $f(x-5)=x-10 \Rightarrow f(x)=x-5.$

I hope you can understand what I mean. Can you tell me that this approach is wrong or true?

> **Problem:**  Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of real numbers. Determine all functions $f:  \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ such that, for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, $$f \big(f(x)f(y)\big) + f(x +y) = f(xy).$$

I ask You to confirm that the solution is sufficient / insufficient / missing / incorrect or correct. Here is my attempts:

> Are there any problems in my substitutions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Student, the less effort people have to put into helping someone, the likelier they actually help you. At least that's my experience regarding form. (If however the content seems to be very interesting, some may move out of their comfort zone and actually bother going through it.) 
Regarding your solution: Looks good.

Comment: When you replace f(x) with x at the start of Case 2, the result only holds for x in the range of f.

Comment: @Empy2 You think it's a deficiency?..

Comment: Yes I think so.  If you applied the same logic in case 1, you would get x=0 for all x.

Comment: Just because the problem says that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, it does not mean the range of $f$ is the whole $\mathbb{R}$.  One of the solutions illustrate this perfectly: $f(x)=0$.  The range is just a singleton $\{0\}$, not the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362996

Answer (score 12):

Empy2 pointed out the error in your proof.  You cannot deduce that $f\big(f(x)f(0)\big)+f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x$ implies $f\big(xf(0)\big)+x=f(0)$ for all $x$.  This only works only for $x$ in the range of $f$.  I am presenting a different solution.

If $f(0)=0$, as you showed, we have
$$f(0)+f(x)=f\big(f(x)f(0)\big)+f(x+0)=f(x\cdot 0)=f(0)$$
so $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.  We assume that $f(0)\ne 0$ from now on.  We claim that $f(c)=0$ implies that $c=1$.

Suppose that $f(c)=0$ for some $c\ne 1$.  Then, we have
$$f\Biggl(f(c)f\left(\frac{c}{c-1}\right)\Biggr)+f\left(c+\frac{c}{c-1}\right)=f\Biggl(c\left(\frac{c}{c-1}\right)\Biggr).$$
That is,
$$f(0)+f\left(\frac{c^2}{c-1}\right)=f\left(\frac{c^2}{c-1}\right),$$
or $f(0)=0$, contradicting the assumption that $f(0)\ne 0$.  Therefore, the hypothesis that $c\ne1$ is false.

Now, we note that for every $x\ne1$, 
$$f\Biggl(f(x)f\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\Biggr)+f\left(x+\frac{x}{x-1}\right)=f\Biggl(x\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\Biggr),$$
so
$$f\Biggl(f(x)f\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\Biggr)+f\left(\frac{x^2}{x-1}\right)=f\left(\frac{x^2}{x-1}\right).$$
So,
$$f\Biggl(f(x)f\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\Biggr)=0$$
and we then conclude from our claim above that
$$f\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)=\frac{1}{f(x)}\tag{1}$$
for every $x\ne 1$.  In particular, this shows that $f(1)=0$, since there does exist $c$ such that $f(c)=0$.

From (1), we get $f(0)=\pm 1$.  Observe that $f$ is a solution if and only if $-f$ is also a solution.  We can without loss of generality assume that $f(0)=-1$.  Plugging $y\mapsto 1$ in the original functional equation, we have
$$-1+f(x+1)=f(0)+f(x+1)=f\big(f(x)f(1)\big)+f(x+1)=f(x\cdot1)=f(x),$$
or
$$f(x+1)=f(x)+1.\tag{2}$$
By induction, $f(x+n)=f(x)+n$ for all integers $n$.

Here, we claim that $f$ is injective.  Suppose that $f(u)=f(v)$ for some $u,v\in\mathbb{R}$.  Pick a positive integer $n$ so large that $4(u+n)< (v+n+1)^2$.  Hence, there are two distinct $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $u+n=ab$ and $v+n+1=a+b$ (since $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the polynomial $t^2-(v+n+1)t+(u+n)$, which have two distinct real roots).  Therefore,
$$f\big(f(a)f(b)\big)+f(a+b)=f(ab)=f(u+n)=f(u)+n.$$
But $f(a+b)=f(v+n+1)=f(v)+n+1=f(u)+n+1$.  That is, by (2), we have $$f\big(f(a)f(b)+1\big)=f\big(f(a)f(b)\big)+1=0.$$  This means $f(a)f(b)+1=1$, or $f(a)f(b)=0$.  Consequently, $f(a)=0$ or $f(b)=0$, which means $a=1$ or $b=1$.  Without loss of generality, $b=1$, so $u+n=ab=a$ and $v+n+1=a+b=a+1$.  That is, $u=a-n=v$.

Now, substitute $y\mapsto 1-x$ in the original functional equation.  We then have
$$f\big(f(x)f(1-x)\big)=f\big(f(x)f(1-x)\big)+f(1)=f\big(x(1-x)\big).$$
Thus, by injectivity,
$$f(x)f(1-x)=x(1-x).$$
Then, we take $y\mapsto -x$ in the original functional equation to get
$$f\big(f(x)f(-x)\big)-1=f\big(f(x)f(-x)\big)+f(0)=f\big(x(-x)\big).$$
Thus,
$$f\big(f(x)f(-x)\big)=f(-x^2)+1=f(-x^2+1)$$
by (2).  By injectivity,
$$f(x)f(-x)=-x^2+1.$$
From (2), we also have
\begin{align}f(x)&=f(x)\Big(\big(f(-x)+1\big)-f(-x)\Big)\\&=f(x)\big(f(1-x)-f(-x)\big)=f(x)f(1-x)-f(x)f(-x),\end{align}
so
$$f(x)=x(1-x)-(-x^2+1)=x-1.$$

It is easy to see that $f(x)=x-1$ is indeed a solution.  Therefore, all solutions are $f(x)=0$, $f(x)=x-1$, and $f(x)=1-x$.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is more of a comment than an answer to the question, but it is too long. 
 Here is the error in the OP's logic.  Injectivity does not imply having an inverse.  Being ***both*** injective and surjective does.  Here is a counterexample to the OP's claim that $f(x)$ can be replaced by $x$ if $f$ is injective.

For a nonnegative integer $k$, let $t_k$ denote $\left\lfloor\dfrac{(-1)^kk}{2}\right\rfloor$.  Then, every integer appears as $t_k$ for exactly once $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$.  Thus, for each $n$, we write $\tau(n)$ for the unique $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $n=t_k$.  In other words,
$$\tau(n)=\begin{cases}2n&\text{if }n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\,,\\-2n-1&\text{if }n\in\mathbb{Z}_{<0}\,.\end{cases}$$ 
(Well, I should have started with defining $\tau$ instead of $\left\{t_k\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}$.)

Now, let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as
$$f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor+\tau\big(\lfloor x\rfloor \big)\tag{*}$$
for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Observe that $f$ is injective and
$$f\big(f(x)\big)=f(x)+\big\lfloor f(x)\big\rfloor$$
for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.   (Certainly, $f$ is not surjective because the range is $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, and not the whole $\mathbb{R}$.)

However, it is not correct to say that
$$f(x)=x+\lfloor x\rfloor$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.   This is because $f(-1)=\tau(-1)=1$ by (*), so $$f(-1)\neq -2=(-1)+\big\lfloor (-1)\big\rfloor\,.$$

---

A possible remedy is given here.  As Zvi said, if $f$ satisfies the functional equation, then so does $-f$.  Thus, in the case $f(0)\neq 0$, it suffices to assume that $f(0)=-1$.  From the OP's work, we have
$$f\big(f(x)\,f(0)\big)+f(x)=f(0)\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.$$
As $f(0)=-1$, we get
$$f\big(-f(x)\big)+f(x)=-1\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.\tag{*}$$
This shows that
$$f\Big(-f\big(-f(x)\big)\Big)+f\big(-f(x)\big)=-1\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.\tag{#}$$
From  (*) and (#), we see that
$$f\Big(-f\big(-f(x)\big)\Big)=f(x)\text{ for each }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.\tag{$\star$}$$

Here is where we can use Zvi's result that $f$ is injective.  Since $f$ is injective, ($\star$) implies that
$$-f\big(-f(x)\big)=x\text{ for each }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.\tag{@}$$
Together with (*), we have
$$-x+f(x)=f\big(-f(x)\big)+f(x)=-1\,,$$
whence
$$f(x)=x-1\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.$$

Note that (@) also implies that $f$ is surjective.  This provides an alternative route as it allows substituting $x$ for $f(x)$ in (*) to get $f(-x)+x=-1$, or $f(-x)=-x-1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Thus, we also arrive at $f(x)=x-1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ in this manner.  I, however, fail to find a way to approach this problem without knowing injectivity of $f$.  It seems to be pivotal to solving the problem.

Comment: (+1) However, I believe that there is proof that this substitution can be made for the particular situation in the question. I think, the error can be repair...

Comment: $f(x)=x+\lfloor x\rfloor$ and What is $f^{-1}(x)$

Comment: The inverse of $f$ does not exist, and $f(x)=x+\lfloor x\rfloor$ only for $x$ in the range of $f$, which is $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$.

Comment: but I said that this substitution can be done if the reverse function is exist in the solution.

Comment: But can you prove that your function $f$ has an inverse?  So far, I have only seen a proof for injectivity by Zvi.  Nobody has shown that $f$ is surjective in the case $f(0)\neq 0$ (except if you know that $f(x)=\pm(x-1)$, of course).

Comment: $ f^{-1}(x)=f(0)(f(0)-x),  x\mapsto f^{-1}(x), x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: But the equation $f(x)=f(0)-\dfrac{x}{f(0)}$ comes from the result $$f\big(f(x)\,f(0)\big)+f(x)=f(0)$$ in the first place, right?  There you already see that you cannot simply write $f\big(x\,f(0)\big)+x=f(0)$ simply because you know $f$ is injective.  As I said, knowing injectivity is insufficient.

Comment: Yes, I made the assumption. Then, based on the result, I tried to prove that the previous assumption was correct. Using the inverse function ..

Comment: Like you said, this approach is wrong. Do you have something on your mind? How do I prove this substitution is correct, without changing the method ,I used?

Comment: I don't have any suggestion, but I do not see how to prove surjectivity without invoking injectivity of $f$.  But when you know injectivity of $f$, Zvi's pathway (after injectivity was proven) seems to be natural.  Trying to verify surjectivity after all this work seems to make things even more complicated.

Comment: In this case, I have to dispose of page 2 ..?

Comment: I found a way to fix your work, but you still need Zvi's injectivity proof.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.  Frankly, you're saying it's not worth the effort?

Comment: I can't answer that.  But I can tell you why I think knowing injectivity is very important in this problem.  As you see from the functional equation, there is no variable outside the function (that is, everything shows up inside at least one $f$, e.g., $f(xy)$ is there, but not $xy$ alone).  Therefore, we need a way to remove $f$ somehow.  Surjectivity is unlikely a probable approach, since we are still stuck with everything inside $f$.  So, injectivity is the only sensible candidate.

Comment: Thank you for explain to me this issues.

Comment: Apart from trivial solutions $f(x)=c$ with $c\in[0,1)$ and the non-trivial solution $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor +\tau\big(\lfloor x\rfloor\big)$, I wonder if there are other solutions $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ to $$f\big(f(x)\big)=f(x)+\big\lfloor f(x)\big\rfloor$$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @Batominovski I tried to correct my mistake. Would you look again?

Comment: You did not improve anything.  The assumption that $f\big(k\,f(0)\big)+k=f(0)$ can be made because you assume $k=f(x)$ in the first place.  Your proof here is basically an instance of circular logic.

Comment: I prove that, the function $f(x)$ cover all real numbers.

Comment: For example,.$f(x)=100$ is possible, here $x=f^2(0)-100f(0)$

Comment: Where is the justification for the equation $f\big(k\,f(0)\big)+k=f(0)$ that you used in your proof?

Comment: for any $k$, I proved that, there exist such a $x$, then $f(x)=k$

Comment: And in that proof, you assumed that $f\big(k\,f(0)\big)+k=f(0)$, which hadn't been proven.

Comment: Well, can we deduce that, $f(f^2(0)-f(x)f(0))=f(x) \Rightarrow f^2(0)-f(x)f(0)=x$

Comment: $f(u)=f(g) \Rightarrow u=g $

Comment: We can, if we know that $f$ is injective, which we do.  So, you are taking us back to Zvi's approach again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85011/discussion-between-student-and-batominovski).

Answer (score 1):

The argument beginning with "We will prove that such $x$ exists" is fallacious. You begin by *assuming* that $k=f(x)$ for some $x$ and you do need that assumption in the following derivation (as otherwise, the functional equation makes no claim about $f(kf(0))$ etc.). At face value, your argument shows

> If $k\in\Bbb R$ and there exists $x$ with $f(x)=k$, then one possible such $x$ is $x=f(0)^2-kf(0)$.

In fact, we see immediately that the bolder claim you try make, i.e.,

> If $k\in\Bbb R$, then there exists $x$ with $f(x)=k$, namely $x=f(0)^2-kf(0)$.

is **false**, simply because the non-surjective
$$\tag1f(x)=0\qquad \text{for all }x\in\Bbb R$$
is obviously a solution.

---

Note that $f(f(0)^2)+f(0)=f(0)$ implies that $0$ is in the image of $f$ (namely $f(x_0)=0$ for $x_0:=f(0)^2$).
Then by setting $y=x_0$, we get
$$ f(0)+f(x+x_0)=f(xx_0)\qquad\text{for all }x.$$
If we find $x$ with $x+x_0=xx_0$, this leads to $f(0)=0$. Indeed, we find such $x$, namely $x=-\frac{x_0}{1-x_0}$ unless $x_0=1$, a case to be treated separately below.

So we have two cases:

- $f(0)=0$. Then with $y=0$, we obtain $f(0)+f(x)=f(0)$, i.e., solution $(1)$.
- $f(0)\ne 0$ and $x_0=1$. Then $f(0)+f(x+1)=f(x)$ and by induction we see that $f(n)=(n-1)a$ with $a:=f(0)$. Then 
  $$ f(f(3)f(0)) + f(3+0)=f(3\cdot 0)\iff f(-2a^2)-2a=a$$
  and
  $$ f(f(-1)f(2)) + f(-1+2)=f((-1)\cdot 2)\iff f(-2a^2)+0=-3a,$$
  whence by elimination of $f(-2a^2)$ we get $f(0)=a=0$, contradiction.

We conclude that $(1)$ is the only solution to the functional equation.

Comment: Dear Teacher, thank you for answer. This edit is my previus edit. I know this is wrong. But, I want to know that, what is the mistake in my logic: "I am assuming the presence of the inverse function: Then, based on the result, I tried to prove that the previous assumption was correct. Using the inverse function" Is this approach wrong?

Comment: I don't understand injectivity. What is general method? I know only this method. For example,$f(x)=x-5, f(y)=y-5 ; f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x-5=y-5 \Rightarrow x=y$

Comment: @Student Yes, as I said, proving X based on the assumption X does not have any logical merit. Let's assume that unicorns exist and live abundantly in the forest. Then by huntung in the forest, we should be able to capture a unicorn, thereby proving tah tunicorns exist

Comment: Now, I understand.. Please, can you explain me injectivity proof for this question. Really, I don't understand..I think for 1 week.But I can not understand..:(

Comment: @Student There is no such thing as an injectivity proof for this problem because there is only one solution, $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, and that is as far from injective as can be

Comment: But, $f(x)=x-1, f(x)=1-x$ are also solution..as far as I know