# Does the image of $f(x)+f(f(x))$ having a hole imply that the image of $f(x)$ has a hole?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an injective function. Assume there exists $a$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x)+f(f(x)) \neq a$. Does that imply that $\exists b, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) \neq b$?

---

This question is a lemma that would be helpful in my attempt to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2995894/prove-that-the-function-f-is-injective/2995907#2995907). I have a feeling that this is false, but have been unable to construct a counterexample.

Comment: What about $f(x)=-x$?

Comment: @Clayton I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you